# Why SignalR js invoke freeze javascript execution

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, signalr

I use Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignarR v. 1.1.0 and I have notices that when I call long execution server side method my browser is freezing

```
connection.invoke("Matches", page).then(function() {
        alert('success');
    })
```

It takes from 3 to 5 seconds (from calling invoke and until I can see 'success' alert) before I can interact with browser. Is it possible to make call 'async'?

Comment: This should be executed asynchronously. Are you setting any global jQuery setting to disable async (since SignalR client internally uses jQuery)?

Comment: I think so too it should be async. No I did not disable jQuery async